# Babylonian numbers in MikTeX

Tags: fonts

I'm trying to typeset babylonian numbers in MikTeX 2.9.6361 Portable. The code babylonian.tex available in https://divisbyzero.com/2012/08/30/ancient-number-systems-in-xetex/ didn't work for me and resulted the following error when compiling with XeLaTeX:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \LaTeX3 error: 
                       Erroneous variable \c__fontspec_shape_n_n_tl used!
l.3806 \emfontdeclare{ \emshape, \eminnershape }

?
```

Can someone help me?

MWE:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,citecolor=red,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[all]{hypcap}



\setlength{\textwidth}{6.2in}
\setlength{\textheight}{9in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0in}

%%%%%Babylonian cuneiform
\usepackage{pgffor, babyloniannum}
\newcommand{\Bnum}[1]{{\LARGE \babyloniannum{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\title{Babylonian cuneiform}
\author{Dave Richeson}

\maketitle

To create \href{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babylonian_numerals}{Babylonian cuneiform numerals} you must download the babyloniannum package at 

\href{http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/xetex/latex/babyloniannum}{http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/xetex/latex/babyloniannum}

You must also download and install the Santakku font from 

\href{http://www.hethport.uni-wuerzburg.de/cuneifont}{http://www.hethport.uni-wuerzburg.de/cuneifont}

Recall that the numbers 1 through 59 are written additively using the symbols 

\begin{center}
\Bnum{1}=1 and\Bnum{10}=10.
\end{center}

For example 47 is written 

\begin{center}
\Bnum{47}
\end{center}

This package is extremely easy to use. To obtain the symbols above type

\verb#\Bnum{47}#

Larger numbers are written in base 60, and this package will do the decomposition for you. For example, 

\[1234567890=1 \cdot 60^{5}+35 \cdot 60^{4}+15 \cdot 60^{3}+35 \cdot 60^{2}+31 \cdot 60^{1}+30 \cdot 60^{0}.\]

and 

\verb#\Bnum{1234567890}#

produces 

\begin{center}
\Bnum{1234567890}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

After running Update MiKTeX twice, the error changed to

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
! 
! The font "Santakku" cannot be found.
! 
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

l.37 \Bnum{1}
             =1 and\Bnum{10}=10.
?
```

The error can be reproduced in your computer by installing Miktex Portable from https://miktex.org/.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Try updating your distro.

Comment: This is quite likely caused by mismatched versions of `fontspec` and `expl3`. Update at least those packages using the MikTeX Update tool. You might have to run 'MikTeX Update' and 'MikTeX Update (Admin)' each twice.

Comment: I had to install `l3experimental` and update `fontspec` to the same date (I could not find a package called `expl3`).

Answer (score 1):

The solution:

I downloaded de Santakku.zip font from http://www.hethport.uni-wuerzburg.de/cuneifont/, unpacked it in the MiKTeX `...\texmfs\config\fontconfig` directory and manually edited the `...\texmfs\config\fontconfig\config\localfonts2.conf` with the directory of the new font in the syntax

```
<dir>Your font directory here</dir>
```

References:

https://www.tug.org/fonts/fontinstall.html

https://www.ctan.org/pkg/babyloniannum

http://www.hethport.uni-wuerzburg.de/cuneifont/

Comment: Given this is cut from the original post you should mark this answer as community wiki.