# Issue compiling with foreign fonts on MikTex 2.9

Tags: fonts, xetex, miktex, fontspec, xepersian

I recently installed MikTex 2.9 and TexMaker on my Windows 7 machine. I tried compiling the following example:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{XB Niloofar}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

But this gives me the following errors: `Erroneous variable \c__fontspec_shape_n_n_tl used!`

Looking at this [thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/387386/babylonian-numbers-in-miktex) it seems that the issue can be a mismatch between versions of `fontspec` and `expl3`. The former has version 2.9e, but the latter I can't find in my package manager (?)

Has anyone experienced something similar?

---

The first part of the log after unsuccesful compilation:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99998 (MiKTeX 2.9.6400 64-bit) (preloaded format=xelatex 2017.10.18)  18 OCT 2017 21:32
entering extended mode
**./tmp.tex
(tmp.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.10> and hyphenation patterns for 76 language(s) loaded.
("C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\book.cls"
Document Class: book 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\bk10.clo"
File: bk10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@chapter=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
("C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\xelatex\xepersian\xepe
rsian.sty"
Package: xepersian 2017/09/06 v19.3 Persian typesetting in XeLaTeX

("C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fontspec\fontspe
c.sty"
("C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\expl3.s
ty"
Package: expl3 2017/09/18 L3 programming layer (loader)

("C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\expl3-c
ode.tex"
Package: expl3 2017/09/18 L3 programming layer (code)
\c_max_int=\count88
\l_tmpa_int=\count89
\l_tmpb_int=\count90
\g_tmpa_int=\count91
\g_tmpb_int=\count92
\g__intarray_font_int=\count93
\g__prg_map_int=\count94
\c_log_iow=\count95
\l_iow_line_count_int=\count96
\l__iow_line_target_int=\count97
\l__iow_one_indent_int=\count98
\l__iow_indent_int=\count99
\c_zero_dim=\dimen103
\c_max_dim=\dimen104
\l_tmpa_dim=\dimen105
\l_tmpb_dim=\dimen106
\g_tmpa_dim=\dimen107
\g_tmpb_dim=\dimen108
\c_zero_skip=\skip43
\c_max_skip=\skip44
\l_tmpa_skip=\skip45
\l_tmpb_skip=\skip46
\g_tmpa_skip=\skip47
\g_tmpb_skip=\skip48
\c_zero_muskip=\muskip10
\c_max_muskip=\muskip11
\l_tmpa_muskip=\muskip12
\l_tmpb_muskip=\muskip13
\g_tmpa_muskip=\muskip14
\g_tmpb_muskip=\muskip15
\l_keys_choice_int=\count100
\c__fp_leading_shift_int=\count101
\c__fp_middle_shift_int=\count102
\c__fp_trailing_shift_int=\count103
\c__fp_big_leading_shift_int=\count104
\c__fp_big_middle_shift_int=\count105
\c__fp_big_trailing_shift_int=\count106
\c__fp_Bigg_leading_shift_int=\count107
\c__fp_Bigg_middle_shift_int=\count108
\c__fp_Bigg_trailing_shift_int=\count109
\l__sort_length_int=\count110
\l__sort_min_int=\count111
\l__sort_top_int=\count112
\l__sort_max_int=\count113
\l__sort_true_max_int=\count114
\l__sort_block_int=\count115
\l__sort_begin_int=\count116
\l__sort_end_int=\count117
\l__sort_A_int=\count118
\l__sort_B_int=\count119
\l__sort_C_int=\count120
\l__tl_build_start_index_int=\count121
\l__tl_build_index_int=\count122
\l__tl_analysis_normal_int=\count123
\l__tl_analysis_index_int=\count124
\l__tl_analysis_nesting_int=\count125
\l__tl_analysis_type_int=\count126
\l__regex_internal_a_int=\count127
\l__regex_internal_b_int=\count128
\l__regex_internal_c_int=\count129
\l__regex_balance_int=\count130
\l__regex_group_level_int=\count131
\l__regex_mode_int=\count132
\c__regex_cs_in_class_mode_int=\count133
\c__regex_cs_mode_int=\count134
\l__regex_catcodes_int=\count135
\l__regex_default_catcodes_int=\count136
\c__regex_catcode_L_int=\count137
\c__regex_catcode_O_int=\count138
\c__regex_catcode_A_int=\count139
\c__regex_all_catcodes_int=\count140
\l__regex_show_lines_int=\count141
\l__regex_min_state_int=\count142
\l__regex_max_state_int=\count143
\l__regex_left_state_int=\count144
\l__regex_right_state_int=\count145
\l__regex_capturing_group_int=\count146
\l__regex_min_pos_int=\count147
\l__regex_max_pos_int=\count148
\l__regex_curr_pos_int=\count149
\l__regex_start_pos_int=\count150
\l__regex_success_pos_int=\count151
\l__regex_curr_char_int=\count152
\l__regex_curr_catcode_int=\count153
\l__regex_last_char_int=\count154
\l__regex_case_changed_char_int=\count155
\l__regex_curr_state_int=\count156
\l__regex_step_int=\count157
\l__regex_min_active_int=\count158
\l__regex_max_active_int=\count159
\l__regex_replacement_csnames_int=\count160
\l__regex_match_count_int=\count161
\l__regex_min_submatch_int=\count162
\l__regex_submatch_int=\count163
\l__regex_zeroth_submatch_int=\count164
\g__debug_trace_regex_int=\count165
\c_empty_box=\box26
\l_tmpa_box=\box27
\l_tmpb_box=\box28
\g_tmpa_box=\box29
\g_tmpb_box=\box30
\l__box_top_dim=\dimen109
\l__box_bottom_dim=\dimen110
\l__box_left_dim=\dimen111
\l__box_right_dim=\dimen112
\l__box_top_new_dim=\dimen113
\l__box_bottom_new_dim=\dimen114
\l__box_left_new_dim=\dimen115
\l__box_right_new_dim=\dimen116
\l__box_internal_box=\box31
\l__coffin_internal_box=\box32
\l__coffin_internal_dim=\dimen117
\l__coffin_offset_x_dim=\dimen118
\l__coffin_offset_y_dim=\dimen119
\l__coffin_x_dim=\dimen120
\l__coffin_y_dim=\dimen121
\l__coffin_x_prime_dim=\dimen122
\l__coffin_y_prime_dim=\dimen123
\c_empty_coffin=\box33
\l__coffin_aligned_coffin=\box34
\l__coffin_aligned_internal_coffin=\box35
\l_tmpa_coffin=\box36
\l_tmpb_coffin=\box37
\l__coffin_display_coffin=\box38
\l__coffin_display_coord_coffin=\box39
\l__coffin_display_pole_coffin=\box40
\l__coffin_display_offset_dim=\dimen124
\l__coffin_display_x_dim=\dimen125
\l__coffin_display_y_dim=\dimen126
\l__coffin_bounding_shift_dim=\dimen127
\l__coffin_left_corner_dim=\dimen128
\l__coffin_right_corner_dim=\dimen129
\l__coffin_bottom_corner_dim=\dimen130
\l__coffin_top_corner_dim=\dimen131
\l__coffin_scaled_total_height_dim=\dimen132
\l__coffin_scaled_width_dim=\dimen133
)
```

Comment: Have you tried to update MikTeX?

Comment: @TeXnician I just installed it an hour ago, literally. Is it necessary to update it?

Comment: you need to update your system expl3 is in both miktex and texlive so you should be able to update via the package manager

Comment: you probably have an old file in your path: show the log file you get from the above example

Comment: Yes. You should run the update manager(s) if you did install  the basic-bundle.

Comment: I did a full install of MikTex with the NetInstaller

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The log is fairly long. I added the first part of it in the OP

Comment: @Texnician @Ulrike Fischer In the Update Manager only 3 packages could be updated, none of them related to `expl3` or fonts as far as I could see

Comment: well you stopped before the fontspec version, I have same version of packages as you plus `Package: fontspec 2017/09/22 v2.6e Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ah, I have `Package: fontspec 2017/03/31 v2.6a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX`

Comment: Then you should update. If those 3 packages contain MikTeX infrastructure you should also check for updates after the update again.

Comment: `expl3` is in `l3kernel`. Maybe you'll need `l3experimental`?

Comment: Don't kill xelatex when you get an error. Type x + enter to finish so that you get a better log.