# Babylonian numerals with Texlive

Tags: fonts, installing-fonts

I successfully used babylonian numerals with xelatex in [Windows with Miktex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/387386/babylonian-numbers-in-miktex), but I would like to do this now in Linux with Texlive.
I installed **texlive2018 portable full** (but without docs and some languages).
When I ran xelatex, the following error occurred:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `babyloniannum.sty' not found.
```

Then, I put the `babylonian-master` folder which contains the `babyloniannum.sty` file in `.../texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/local/` (Is this the correct location?) and after running `texhash`, the next error was:

```
! Package fontspec Error: The font "Santakku" cannot be found.
```

I have the folder `santakku` with only these files:

```
Paleo-Babylonien.pdf
Santakku.ttf
SantakkuM.ttf
```

so, where should I put it? And how to tell xelatex to use it?

**Note:** I need to do without sudo password.

Comment: And one more question: Why don't texlive-full comes with this font?

Comment: for the fonts your can try `texmf-local/fonts/truetype/...`. Perhaps you will to call the fonts by filename and not by fontname. For the pdf it depends. If is a docu, put it in texmf-local/doc/latex, if it is needed at runtime, it should be in texmf-local/tex/latex.

Comment: Why do you expect texlive to contain a font which is only available from an external website?

Comment: Now I understand: this font isn't a official one from Texlive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put `babyloniannum.sty` in some place where TeX will find it, for instance in

```
/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/babyloniannum
```

(in this case remember to run `mktexlsr` as superuser). Otherwise keep it in the work directory. Fetch the Santakku font and again place it in a suitable directory under `texmf-local`, or in the work directory. In the example below I used the latter approach.

Then fix the most obvious glitch in the package, which is using `\fontspec` at every call of `\babyloniannum`. It's much better to define a specific font face.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{babyloniannum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\let\babylonianfont\relax
\newfontface{\babylonianfont}{Santakku}[
  Extension=.ttf,
  Path=./,
]

\patchcmd{\babyloniannum}
 {\fontspec{\babylonianfont}}
 {\babylonianfont}
 {}{}

\begin{document}

\babyloniannum{424000}
\babyloniannum{42}

\end{document}
```

[image]

There are also a couple of spurious spaces to be removed. Before editing, from

```
X\babyloniannum{424000}X\babyloniannum{42}X
```

I get

[image: spurious]

With the following edits (that make also redundant the suggested `\patchcmd`)

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1999/12/01]
\ProvidesPackage{babyloniannum}%%%% EDITED
    [2011/08/19 0.5 Typeset Babylonian numerals with XeTeX and LuaTeX]
\ProvidesPackage{babyloniannum}
\RequirePackage{fontspec}
%\RequirePackage{xunicode}
\RequirePackage{numname}
\newcommand{\babylonianfont}{Santakku}
\newcommand{\unicodedisp}[1]{\char"#1}
\newcommand{\babylonian}[1]{%
  \protect\babyloniannum{\arabic{#1}}}
\newcommand{\babylonianglyph}[1]{%
\ifnum #1 > \z@ % glyph is not zero
  \chardef\m@mten=10 % cuts by units of 10
  \numdigits{#1}% parse number
  \ifcase\c@xsm@mctr %
    \relax %
    \or
    \unicodedisp{1230B} %10
    \or
    \unicodedisp{1230B}\kern-0.15em{}\unicodedisp{1230B} %20 -- unknown?
    \or
    \unicodedisp{1230D} %30
    \or
    \unicodedisp{1240F} %40
    \or
    \unicodedisp{12410} %50
  \fi
  \ifnum \c@ism@mctr > \z@ %
    \ifnum \c@xsm@mctr > \z@ %
  \kern-0.5em{} % make glyphs closer
    \fi %
  \fi %
  \ifcase\c@ism@mctr %
    \or
    \unicodedisp{12079} %1
    \or
    \unicodedisp{1222B} %2
    \or
    \unicodedisp{12408} %3
    \or
    \unicodedisp{120FB} %4
    \or
    \unicodedisp{1240A} %5
    \or
    \unicodedisp{1240B} %6
    \or
    \unicodedisp{1240C} %7
    \or
    \unicodedisp{1240D} %8
    \or
    \unicodedisp{1240E} %9
  \fi
  \addtocounter{baby@glyphs}{1}%
\else
  \ifnum\c@baby@glyphs > \z@ %
\kern0.5em{}% empty space for zero
  \fi
\fi
}
\newcounter{baby@ism@mctr}  % "units"
\newcounter{baby@xsm@mctr}  % "tens"
\newcounter{baby@csm@mctr}  % "hundreds"
\newcounter{baby@ksm@mctr}  % "thousands"
\newcounter{baby@xksm@mctr} % "ten thousands"
\newcounter{baby@cksm@mctr} % "hundred thousands"
\newcounter{baby@msm@mctr}  % "millions"
\newcounter{baby@xmsm@mctr} % "ten millions"
\newcounter{baby@cmsm@mctr} % "hundred millions"
\newcounter{baby@bsm@mctr}  % "billions"
\newcommand{\babylonian@setcounters}{%
  \setcounter{baby@ism@mctr}{\c@ism@mctr}%
  \setcounter{baby@xsm@mctr}{\c@xsm@mctr}%
  \setcounter{baby@csm@mctr}{\c@csm@mctr}%
  \setcounter{baby@ksm@mctr}{\c@ksm@mctr}%
  \setcounter{baby@xksm@mctr}{\c@xksm@mctr}%
  \setcounter{baby@cksm@mctr}{\c@cksm@mctr}%
  \setcounter{baby@msm@mctr}{\c@msm@mctr}%
  \setcounter{baby@xmsm@mctr}{\c@xmsm@mctr}%
  \setcounter{baby@cmsm@mctr}{\c@cmsm@mctr}%
  \setcounter{baby@bsm@mctr}{\c@bsm@mctr}%
}
\newcounter{baby@glyphs}%
\newcommand{\babyloniannum}[1]{%
  \chardef\m@mten=60 % Cut by units of 60
  \numdigits{#1}% Parse number
  \babylonian@setcounters%
  \mbox{%
  \babylonianfont
  \setcounter{baby@glyphs}{0}%
  \babylonianglyph{\c@baby@bsm@mctr}%
  \babylonianglyph{\c@baby@cmsm@mctr}%
  \babylonianglyph{\c@baby@xmsm@mctr}%
  \babylonianglyph{\c@baby@msm@mctr}%
  \babylonianglyph{\c@baby@cksm@mctr}%
  \babylonianglyph{\c@baby@xksm@mctr}%
  \babylonianglyph{\c@baby@ksm@mctr}%
  \babylonianglyph{\c@baby@csm@mctr}%
  \babylonianglyph{\c@baby@xsm@mctr}%
  \babylonianglyph{\c@baby@ism@mctr}%
  }%
}
\endinput
%%
%% End of file `babyloniannum.sty'.
```

the output is

[image]